# ToolTip Style ToolTipService.ShowDuration

Tags: wpf, tooltip

The Property ToolTipService.ShowDuration is not effected
The other properties are set
How to set ToolTipService.ShowDuration via a Style?

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip">
       <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI SemiLight" />
       <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="20000" />
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushLightBlue}" />
</Style>
```

Specifically I am having this problem with a MenuItem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TooltipService.ShowDuration` attached property should be set on the element having the `ToolTip`. For instance:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="20000" />
</Style>
```

For a MenuItem this should work

```
<Style TargetType="Menu">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="20000"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Yes I can make it work on Button but not on a MenuItem.  I will expand the question.  Sorry for not being more complete.